# HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect in Google Cloud Load Balancer doesn't work for multiple domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm unable to redirect HTTP-traffic to HTTPS for 2 domains that point to the same load balancer setup. While the redirect for `http://domain1.com` is working fine, on `http://domain2.com` the following error is shown:

[image: 404 error for http domain]

**Setup**

Load balancer with a single host/path rule to serve a single website:
[image: host and path rule]

2 HTTPS forwarding rules (ipv4 & ipv6) targeting a proxy containing a single Google-managed HTTPS-certificate for the 2 domains.

Both domains have their A- and AAAA-records set to the same IP-addresses of the LB and display the website on https-domains `https://domain1.com` and `https://domain2.com`.

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) to setup another LB that will redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

This works fine for `http://domain1.com` (it redirects correctly to the https-version), but it doesn't for `http://domain2.com` (it displays the 404 error).

The http-to-https LB contains a single rule as described in the guide:
[image]

How can I ensure the HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect is working for all domains pointing to the LB?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are little confuse about what is HTTP-to-HTTPS. Because HTTP-to-HTTPS requires two Load Balancer, one to the HTTPS pointing to the port 443 and other load balancers without backends to forward the HTTP to HTTPS.

[To redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, you must do the following:](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-http-https-redirect?hl=en#architecture)

1. (Prerequisite) You must have an external HTTPS load balancer (called here LB1) that is already serving HTTPS traffic on port 443.
2. Create a partial external HTTP load balancer (called here LB2). The LB2 setup has the following:

-No backend

-The same frontend IP address used by LB1

-A redirect configured in the URL map

[Another theme is URL Map to route requests to backend services or backend buckets and URL redirects your domain's visitors from one URL to another.](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts?hl=en#url-redirects)

**Redirect example**

You want

HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect

**Redirect**

http://host.name/path

to

https://host.name/path

**Accomplished using a default URL redirect**

```
    kind: compute#urlMap
    name: web-map-http
    defaultUrlRedirect:
      httpsRedirect: True
```